# GCP Cloud Source Repository permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Has someone implemented a way to define permission **on a per repository-base** on [Cloud Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/)?

I have two repos under the same project, one of which needs to be restricted **only to a specific group**, but I cannot find a way (even with custom roles) to restrict access to that group.

Either you grant read access or write access, but not specifying the repo.

It seems quite a basic security feature...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in Google Cloud Platform you will find that permissions are **not applied on an instance or single object basis** (such as a single instance), but rather, permissions are applied to all instances of **a specific kind of resource**. The permission system which controls all of this is [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/), which exists on a per project basis (folder and organization also).

So for example, if you want to **create** an instance and afterwards **modify** it and change its configuration values, you need to have an **IAM role** such as the **Compute Instance Admin role**, which will in fact let you modify any existing instance within the project, although with the GCE instance resource for example, you can get a *finer granularity level* and give an user permissions to handle just one instance ([source](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1)).

A more detailed explanation on permissions for GCP and IAM in [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#concepts_related_to_access_management).

In your specific case, according to the documentation you can only grant permissions at the project level and above, meaning that you can't give permissions to a single user or group to a specific repo, but rather, to all GSR repositories in that project.

**I guess one thing you could do** is to create **a separate project for one group**, and in that project you can create the GSR repository which must only be accessed by such a group.

Comment: Hi Pau,
I also thought about using a different project; my problem however is that IAM permissions are inherited from above, so unless I break the dependencies (or create a project outside of that folder), I cannot pursue the method you outline.

Comment: Well, if the permissions at inherited from the folder, you could just create another folder and create the project in the other folder, or directly outside (as you point out). If they are otherwise inherited from the organization itself, then your only way to achieve my workaround would be to remove these permissions from the organization so they aren't inherited.

Comment: Yep!
I ended up moving the project outside of that particular folder to break inheritance of the specific group.
In this way, I was able to add the group only to the specific GSR repository through its permission page here (https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access)

Comment: Cheers to that mate :-)